# Converting HTML string, including style, to PDF (Electron - React - Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdf, electron

**_____ Project Overview _____**

I am building an Electron application, using React and Typescript, in which I read a plain HTML string to memory to then adjust some elements in it and finally convert it to a pdf.

**_____ Problem Description _____**

Because the html is never really rendered (it is just in memory), I am uncertain on how to convert the html (with style) to a pdf without rendering the html first.

**_____ What I've tried _____**

- I have tried using a combination of `html2canvas` and `jspdf`.
  `jspdf` works fine to convert the HTML, without styling, to pdf, but
  I need the styling. So I tried getting a "screenshot" of my page with
  `html2canvas` first but that fails because the page is never
  rendered.
- I tried using `electron-pdf`, but I could not get this to work in my application. It works fine as a command line tool though, so an option would be to invoke the command line tool. I think that that should work, but it feels very hacky (so I'd prefer not going that route).

**_____ Code _____**

```
const createPDF = async (invoiceData: IInvoiceFields) => {
  const invoiceTemplate = fs
    .readFileSync(
      resolve(
        remote.app.getAppPath(),
        "src",
        "invoice_templates",
        "invoice_EN.html"
      )
    )
    .toString();
  const invoiceHTMLString = fillInInvoice(invoiceTemplate, invoiceData);
  const domParser = new DOMParser();
  const invoiceHTMLDocument = domParser.parseFromString(
    invoiceHTMLString,
    "text/html"
  );
  // TODO: Create actual pdf...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Generating PDF with Electron.js](https://medium.com/@ishwar.rimal/generating-pdf-with-electron-js-31b59ac93249), it seems possible to use the [webContents](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents) method [printToPDF](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprinttopdfoptions-callback) in a new BrowserWindow without actually showing the window:

```
window_to_PDF = new BrowserWindow({show : false});//to just open the browser in background

window_to_PDF.loadURL('anylink.html'); //give the file link you want to display

function pdfSettings() {
    var paperSizeArray = ["A4", "A5"];
    var option = {
        landscape: false,
        marginsType: 0,
        printBackground: false,
        printSelectionOnly: false,
        pageSize: paperSizeArray[settingCache.getPrintPaperSize()-1],
    };
  return option;
}

window_to_PDF.webContents.on("did-finish-load", function() {
  window_to_PDF.webContents.printToPDF(pdfSettings(), function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          //do whatever you want
          return;
      }
      try{
          fs.writeFileSync('./generated_pdf.pdf', data);
      }catch(err){
          //unable to save pdf..
      }
  });
});
```

So, in your case, you may have to write your generated HTML to a temporary file `anylink.html` then use [loadURL](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options) or preferably [loadFile](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) to load it in the "off-screen" window.

Comment: This works, thanks for that! But it is important to note that you have to wait for the `webContents` to finish loading before you can call `printToPDF`. If you do not do this, the generated pdf will just be white.

Comment: Glad it works! Thanks for sharing this info about the need to wait for the contents to get fully loaded before actually calling `printToPDF`, that is very helpful.